# Prove the integral inequality

Tags: real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals, integral-inequality

$$\frac{\pi}{4}-\frac{1}{2}\le \int_0^1{\frac{\arcsin x}{1+x^8}}\le \frac{\pi}{2}-1$$

I can say that I have close to zero experience with integral inequalities. I've searched for couple of theorems most of them involving monotonous function on $[0,1]$. Arcsin is increasing in this case and the other one is decreasing. You could say we have a product of increasing and decreasing function on this interval however I didn't find any theorems that cover this case. Also this integral doesn't seem to have elementary function.

Another thing I noticed is that most of the theorems cover only 1 part of this inequality; either $\le or \ge$ so my guess is we need some type of combination or perhaps find a new integral that is equal to $\frac{\pi}{4}-\frac{1}{2}$ and another that is equal to $\frac{\pi}{2}-1$.

What's the correct approach when we need to prove that the value of certain integral is in a provided interval?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the bound on the right, 
$$
\int_0^1{\frac{\arcsin x}{1+x^8}}\,dx\leq \int_0^1\arcsin x\,dx=\frac\pi2-1. 
$$
For the bound on the left, 
$$
\int_0^1{\frac{\arcsin x}{1+x^8}}\,dx\geq\frac12\,\int_{0}^1{{\arcsin x}}\,dx=\frac12\,\left(\frac\pi2-1\right)=\frac\pi4-\frac12. 
$$

Comment: I thought of the same thing moment before you posted for that first part. Thanks!

Comment: There is a problem with my second estimate. I have edited, to an easier argument.